# Decoding the Payload present in DOMAIN_EVENT_ENTRY

Tags: java, spring-boot, axon

I've started exploring axon framework.
I'm following this [tutorial](https://github.com/ajcatambay/cqrs-bank-account-demo)
It is basically creating an account, retrieving information about the account and few other activities.
Whenever an event takes place, an entry is stored in Domain Event Entry Table. The payload is also present in hashed form . My questions are :

1. Is it possible to access the entries present in Domain Event Entry table ?If yes , then how?
2. Also, If I want to add the query and do log it in the console, does the payload appear in hashed form or in the original format.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the project you shared, I would start by upgrading the version you are using. I can see it's using `4.4.3` while latest is `4.5.3` and it brings lots of improvements and new features.

Before going to your questions, I believe it is important to note some things here.

1. This project is NOT using Axon Server, so your Events are stored on a Database of your choice. In this case, since you have JPA on your classpath, Axon Framework will automatically configure a `JpaEventStorageEngine` for you. Similar to the `TokenStore` implementation.
2. It is important to know about the Serializers as well, and for that I will refer to the [official docs](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-serialization). Configuring them, you can have your Events stored as `XML` or `JSON`.

So, to your questions now:

1. Yes, you can access them as you would do in a normal database. Since I can see on the project it has `/h2-console` [enabled](https://github.com/ajcatambay/cqrs-bank-account-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml#L4), going there would be my first choice. Alternatively, you can configure any tool/app capable of checking the contents of your database.
2. For logging the query, you have to configure Hibernate for example for logging that. In any case, it will log it as a deserialized object and not as a 'payload' form. Of course, you can write some queries for the `DomainEventEntry` table and log the payload but that's not how you are supposed to use that table.

For more info, I would recommend going to the [official docs](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/) or to our [Axon Academy](https://academy.axoniq.io/)!

---

Edit 1: adding info about `QueryHandler`

Axon Framework offers, as you noted, `@QueryHandler` annotation which should be part of your Query side (appart from the Command side, derived from CQRS concept). That is the side responsible for providing information based on Events (from your Event Store a.k.a. `DomainEventEntry` in your case). Basically, `Event`s will be propagated to the Query side where you will have one or more `EventHandler`s components/methods responsible to handle the Event and write the derived result to a form of storage (usually a relational database). You also have one or more `QueryHandler`s components/methods that will get `Query` messages, perform the query it (using a `Repository` for example) and return the response to the caller. In that sense, you can really tailor your query side the way you want! The [ref guide](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/queries/query-handlers) has some info about Query Handlers that I recommend!

Comment: CamposThanks for giving such a detailed explanation. 
I want to ask then how should I write queries for accessing the stored events since you have mentioned that querying DomainEventEntry isn't the way I should do. I've joined the Axon Academy and looked into official docs. It does mentions about QueryHandler but I'm not able to grasp that concept properly. Can you suggest some good source where I can see on how it is implemented? Thanks once again .

Comment: I am glad to help! I've added an edit to the answer above explaining a bit about Query Handlers in general.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can access the events in the domain events table. With H2 you can log in to the H2 console and find it there.
2. If you use a query the payload will be deserialized (no XML or JSON) and can be used to log information or whatever you need to do.